# javacomplete plugin for vim

Tags: vim

I have two questions but they are both related to the use of same plugin so I decided to ask them in the same question.

I have started using [javacomplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1785) plugin for omnicomplete in vim. I have set `omnicomplete` using:

```
setlocal omnifunc=javacomplete#Complete
```

and it seems to be working with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd> but there is also a mention of `completefunc` in the documentation such as:

```
setlocal completefunc=javacomplete#CompleteParamsInfo
```

which doesn't seem to be doing anything with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd> and I'm not sure what it is supposed to do anyways. Has anyone managed to set this up?

Also I was wondering if it's possible to move `Reflection.class` somehow from `$HOME` to `~/.vim` so that it won't pollute the system?

Answer (score 2):

That's `<C-x><C-o>` and `<C-x><C-u>`, not `<C-o>`/`<C-u>`.

The doc says to put `javacomplete.vim`, `java_parser.vim` and `Reflection.java` in `~/.vim/autoload/`, did you do that?

The plugin doesn't seem to include an option for the path to `Reflection.class` but, reading the `GetJavaCompleteClassPath` function at line 1748 of `javacomplete.vim` it looks like the script is expecting that file to be in one of two locations: `~/.vim/autoload/Reflection.class` or `~/Reflection.class`.

So yes. You can move it safely to `~/.vim/autoload`, with its friends.

Comment: Those are the keys I am actually using, but it's still not working. I edited the question for keys now. I had installed using `vundle` and moving to `~/.vim/bundle/autoload/Reflection.class` has indeed worked, thanks..

Comment: Did you add the two mappings as well as the `set completefunc` line?

Comment: mappings are just for convenience I guess, but I added anyways. still not working..

Comment: Yes they are for convenience. Judging by the name of the function I would say it's used to complete function parameters; is that the context where you are doing `<C-x><C-u>`?

Comment: so let's say I have a string `s`. I type `s.getChars(` and then `<C-x><C-u>` and it makes it `s.getChars(getChars(`. If I type `<C-x><C-u>` again after this, nothing happens.

Comment: I guess.. But I will leave the question open in case someone comes up with a fix or something.